# Only fire local notification if condition is met

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, notifications

So I have a working app that sends notifications every day reminding you to mark something complete.  Right now the problem is that even when they have marked all requirements, they still get the notification.  Is there a way to conditionally fire a notification?  For example, only fire the notification if A==false.

Comment: you need to remove that notification from notification 's pending list instead of condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user marks all requirements, remove the corresponding notification from the notification center.